# OpenGL shader loading fails on MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, shader

I have a function which is supposed to load a shader:

```
- (GLuint)compileShaderOfType:(GLenum)type file:(NSString *)file
{
    GLuint shader;
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    const GLchar *shaderText = (GLchar *)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil] cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    if (nil == shaderText)
    {
        [NSException raise:kFailedToInitialiseGLException format:@"Failed to read shader file %@", file];
    }

    shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderText, NULL);
    // Compile shader
    glCompileShader(shader);
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        NSLog(@"Shader source loading failed with error:\n%s", infoLog);
    }

    return shader;
}
```

The result of running the code produces an error: "Shader source loading failed with error:". `infoLog` is empty. `shader` is equal to zero. But shader text got loaded successfully. I am trying to follow the Apple Developer Tutorial which I think is deprecated for the current version of OpenGL, but there is nothing else better out there on MacOS and OpenGL (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_shaders/opengl_shaders.html). Also following this tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Shaders. Running latest version of MacOS and XCode, so I am assuming I am using the latest version of OpenGL. Why is `glShaderSource` leaving `shader` unaffected?
My guess: the string is not null terminated. I've added '\0' to the end of the file, but that did not help. Not sure how to null terminate a string in Objective C.

Comment: You clearly can't check the `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` before actually compiling the shader.

Comment: @Vallentin got the glCompileShader(shader); in the wrong place. I've corrected that. Still the same issue though.

Comment: @genpfault that actually was the issue. Sorry, didn't know. when I worked with openGL in drawRect function, the context was not set. Apple documentation has a mention of it, but not for the section where they describe work with NSOpenGLView, which is what I am using. I guess NSOpenGLView sets current context itself, but sometime later.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to get info for compilation errors is:

```
glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if ( success == GL_FALSE )
{
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &success);
    if ( success > 0 )
    {
        int nChars = 0;
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 512, &nChars, infoLog);
        NSLog(@"Shader source loading failed with error:\n%s", infoLog);
    }
}
```